# Running Four Queries on Three Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL and going on things i've read in various places I've managed to chop together this script, unfortunately the output isn't quite what I expected, I get lots of:

```
Buffer Status 2H: Notice: Undefined variable: row in /var/www/secretbit/allbuff.php on line 53 0 records. <br />
Buffer Status TC: Notice: Undefined variable: row in /var/www/secretbit/allbuff.php on line 54 0 records. <br />
Buffer Status ST: Notice: Undefined variable: row in /var/www/secretbit/allbuff.php on line 55 0 records. <br />
Buffer Status 3C: Notice: Undefined variable: row in /var/www/secretbit/allbuff.php on line 56 0 records <br />
```

And here is the code I've used to compile this monster:

```
 <?php

 error_reporting(-1);
 ini_set('display_errors', true);

 $con = mysqli_connect(
   '192.168.20.10',
   'root2',
   'password',
   'contaque'
 );

 $con2 = mysqli_connect(
   '192.168.20.222',
   'root2',
   'password',
   'contaque'
 );

 $con3 = mysqli_connect(
   '192.168.20.8',
   'root2',
   'password',
   'contaque'
 );

 $res = mysqli_query(
 $con,
  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total1' FROM contaque_hopper WHERE  campaign_id = 'CLOSERUK';"
 );

 $res = mysqli_query(
 $con2,
  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total2' FROM contaque_hopper WHERE  campaign_id = 'CLOSERTC';"
 );

 $res = mysqli_query(
 $con2,
  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total3' FROM contaque_hopper WHERE  campaign_id = 'CLOSERST';"
 );

 $res = mysqli_query(
 $con3,
  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total4' FROM contaque_hopper WHERE  campaign_id = 'CLOSER3C';"
 );

 echo 'Buffer Status 2H: ', (int)$row['total1'], ' records. <br />';
 echo 'Buffer Status TC: ', (int)$row['total2'], ' records. <br />';
 echo 'Buffer Status ST: ', (int)$row['total3'], ' records. <br />';
 echo 'Buffer Status 3C: ', (int)$row['total4'], ' records. <br />';

 ?>
```

Comment: really bad formatting. use the appropriate formatting buttons at the top of the textarea when composing your message. i'll do it for you this time.

Answer (score 4):

Well it looks like `$row` is undefined. I think you probably need to use the method [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to get the results of the queries.